# Terminology for scenario when energy of system $E(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k)$ with $k$ real parameters, is minimum whenever $\theta_1=c$ (fixed value)

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, chaos-theory, critical-phenomena, bifurcation

**Disclaimer.** I'm not a physicist.

---

Consider a physical system whose "energy" $E$ is a function of $k$ real parameters $\theta = (\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k) \in \mathbb R^k$. Let $E_{\min}$ be the minimum possible energy for the system (e.g zero). Let $c \in \mathbb R$ be a fixed scalar (say, $0$, $\pi$, $e$, etc.)

> **Question.** *In physics, is there a standard terminology for the scenario where $E(\theta) = E_{\min}$ whenever $\theta_1 = c$ (irrespective of the other $k-1$ parameters of the system) , while $E(\theta) > E_\min$ otherwise. That is, every configuration $\theta$ has minimal energy if and only if the first parameter $\theta_1$ is fixed to the value $c$.*

For example, could one say something like "A global bifurcation of co-dimension 1 occurs at $\theta_1 = c$. " ?

Comment: I don't think theres a general term for something so specific. The best you can do is state it more concisely, though there is really nothing wrong with the description which you gave.

Comment: There are $k-1$ unfixed parameters so in QFT we would say there is a moduli space of vacua with dimension $k-1$. Everything else about the setup (how many fixed parameters there are, how we label them and what co-ordinate system makes them constant) is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. Is "moduli space" just a fancy word for preimage of a real set under the energy functional $E$ (here, in fact a level set), and is vacuum just the set $E^{-1}(\{E_{\min}\}) := \{\theta \mid E(\theta) = E_{\min}\}$ ?

Comment: That is how I always see it used in physics. And for a value larger than $E_{\mathrm{min}}$, the level set would be a "moduli space of excited states" even though that's a less interesting concept.

Comment: This terminology is borrowed from math where instead of an energy functional that's constant, it's something like the genus. For example, the torus has a complex structure modulus. So the moduli space of genus 1 Riemann surfaces has two real dimensions. Specifically, it is the upper half plane quotiented by $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ also known as the fundamental domain.

Comment: Great. Thanks again.